# Calling a function of the derived class from a variable type of parent class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I am learning Object Oriented Programming.  I wrote the following simple program, but I don't follow why the call `b->derived_function();` doesn't work.  I understand the base class `Base` does not have a member function with that name, but since I do: `b = new Derived();`, shouldn't `b` be an object of the `Derived` class (making the function call valid)?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void base_function() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void base_function() {
        cout<<"base_function"<<"\n";
    }

    void derived_function() {
        cout<<"derived_function"<<"\n";
    }   
};

int main() {
    Base* b;
    b = new Derived();
    
    // b->base_function();  //works
    b->derived_function();  //doesn't work; why?
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a repro on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/02UbGQ).  Thanks!

Comment: `b` has a static type (compile time) of `Base*`.  `Base` doesn't have a `derived_function`

Comment: When you have a pointer to a `Base*` whatever you assign to it will be viewed as though it is a `Base`. Doesn't matter if it's a `Base`, something derived from `Base`, or you have a bug and it's not a `Base` at all. In general pointers are really dumb. They only know they point at something and that the something must be a `Base`. A whole lot of magic has to happen behind the scenes, and it can be expensive so you have to ask for it by name, to find out that it's actually pointing at a derived class.